# How to return a result through multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, handler

in some part of my application there is a structure of activities like this:

[image]

`Activity A` is my home activity where I come back after each process or flow.
`Activity B` is a simple confirmation activity.
`Activity C` is another confirmation activity.
`Activity D` does some process and finally it gets back the result to my home activity (`Activity A`).

### Requirements:

`Activity B` and `C`:

- must be there and cannot be merged in one.
- when it is clicked on the cancel button it calls `finish()` and does nothing.
- when it is clicked on the OK button it follows the flow and the current activity calls `finish()`

### Question:

I was thinking about using `startActivityForResult()` but I have never used it to pass a result through multiple activities..
I also was thinking to pass a `handler` (created in `Activity A`) which calls some method on `Activity A` and is executed on `Activity D`...
How could I implement it?

Comment: I am also facing above this issue with two app with multiple activities. Please refer and reply if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735674/how-to-get-data-onactivityresult-from-external-app-activity-using-seresult-or-st/38736824#

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You might like to make use of the intent flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT** as described in [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) when starting activities B and C

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity. This way the new activity can call `setResult(int)` and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity.

That way A should pick up any data sent back in the extras sent back from D

Comment: This only works if the intermediate Activities are finished() along the way. If B or C are not finished(), A's onActivityResult() method is not called. Chaining startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() works whether or not the intermediate Activities are finished().

Comment: It works nice! Thanks for share. I finish() the intermediate activity after the call of startActivity() with the intent that contains the flag.

Comment: I am also facing above this issue with two app with multiple activities. Please refer and reply..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735674/how-to-get-data-onactivityresult-from-external-app-activity-using-seresult-or-st/38736824#

Answer (score 11):

Yup, great formatting. And you can -- and probably should -- definitely call `startActivityForResult()` from each of Activity A, B, and C (and don't `finish()` right away). In B and C you can check for a successful result and `finish()`, passing the result on back to A.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == MY_RESULT_CODE)) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

If you want B and C to disappear regardless, do the following instead:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    setResult(resultCode, data);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This implementation is correct, but I really needed those activities to disapear (in order to prevent a back button press). In my case, it was easier to implement the way @NickT described.

Comment: How do you determine which `requestCode` your activity B was started with? I launch B from A with several request codes (for example if I want to modify or add a new entry, it's the same activity B, but with different request codes).
So how do I startActivityForResult from activity B to activity C?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question but I wanted to put in a valid solution, use `onNewIntent()` and treat it as `onActivityResult()`.

In activity D you would structure your intent as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext, Activity_A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("someName", data);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and then in Activity_A

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // update your UI
    intent.getSerializableExtra(...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do B and C as dialogs that are fired from A and only if B and C are ok, you run D with `startActivityForResult()`