# Sharing state across Android activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having trouble passing along state data between different activities. Right now I have four of them:

- A coordinates between activities (a big onActivityResult method) and has no real UI (just a blank layout)
- B adds some data (String)
- C adds some data (taking pictures)
- D shows a review of the data before uploading it, state is deleted afterwards

First I stored the state of this workflow in the instance variables of activity A, but most of the time Android had garbage collected A when returning from B (probably because of orientation changes) so I was getting Null Pointer Exceptions. Then I tried storing state inside a parcelable object, which was created when B returned to A with a result, and then passing along that object to C. It arrives at C fine, but when I'm parceling the object again from C to return to A it doesn't arrive for some reason. This results in another NPE when trying to hand the object from A to D.

In the end, the data needs to be deleted: either by D after uploading or if you close the app halfway and don't complete all the activities. You would start over again at A (or B, which is an actual usable activity).

By now my current structure is feeling way more complex then it should be. I think activity A should be cut out. But I'm unsure on what to implement in its place. **Also I'm unsure on how to make activity C repeatable for 2 or 3 times**, with each time adding data, before going to D. Possible solutions I've found:

- Use intents with FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT and chain activities together as described in [How to return a result through multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135449/how-to-return-a-result-through-multiple-activities)
- Using a Service to manage state
- From [the book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-4-Application-Development.productCd-1118102274.html) that's currently on my desk: using Fragments to store state (with the setRetainInstance method)
- Extending android.app.Application to manage state
- Storing state in SharedPreferences (but where would I do the housekeeping?)

I'm new to Android development... I'll probably could get all of them working sooner or later, but what is the proper solution for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay more attention to [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). In your case it would be enough to use [extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) in your [intents and results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities). Services and SharedPreferences are definitely not what you want. Extending Application is a good option in case of very complex or huge data, but this does not look like your case.

Comment: I was about to type up "but I'm using extras already!" but then I took another good luck at my code and noticed that I was using getIntent().getParcelableExtra() in activity As onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) method, instead of intent.getParcelableExtra(). No wonder I was getting NPEs - changed 'intent' to 'resultIntent' for good measure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android.app.Application class
```

In your app, it is application level class and it is created automatically by configuring it in menifest.xml file.
You can access this class in activity by

```
getApplication();
```

You can set application level data in this class and from one activity and use it in another activity