# How to pass data in between activities

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview

How to handle this scenario in Android.

Regular flow.

```
Listview--> On_item_click-->Activityforresult-->Launch_edit_activity-->updateData-->onSave-->Set_result-->Refresh_listview.
```

Notification flow (i'm stuck here)

```
NotificationActivity-->Launch_edit_activity-->updateData-->onSave-->(SetResult is happening in existing flow). But it will break.
```

Like this i'm doing on finish

```
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
```

How to make setResult goes to Listview when i launch the edit screen from notification?

Comment: What about starting the ListView activity with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT intent flag set?  Here's an example of how to use it.  I think it would solve your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135449/how-to-return-a-result-through-multiple-activities

Comment: Hey, thanks. How about setting setType("String"); and in the receiving activity we can use getType();, check it set flag and make operation does it ok?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary or not.  You should be able to verify the result code in onActivityResult.  If the information you're giving back is different from regular flow I'd find a way to make the request codes different for each flow.  Then onActivityResult could determine which data it's supposed to receive.