# StartActivityResult and StartActivity for multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have three Activities.

- **Activity A**: startActivityResult  calling Activity B and getback to A
  with Data
- **Activity B**: only startActivity to Activity C and send Data to
  Activity C.
- **Activity C**: Now here i want to getData from B send to A with
  startActivityResult.

**How to go Activity C to A with data with**

```
setResult(); finish();
```

**method?**

Answer (score 1):

Just as you go from ActivityB to ActivityC giving data, use the same method (start intent with Bundle I suppose) to go from ActivityC to ActivityA.
In ActivityA, check if there's Bundle, and react if there's something.

Comment: I have a Add button in Activity A , Now Activity B is Camera_photo capture that capture image and send to A with startActivityResult, and activity B has video button that calls  startActivity to C to capture Video,  Activity C has video capture button and go to Activity D now i want  Activity D to A with video Data

Comment: So, you're doing it wrong. Make a DialogAlert in ActivityA and let user choose between ActivityB(camera) & ActivityC(video), start both with startActivityForResult and get the result of both.

Comment: I cant do that its my flow ! Is there any solutions?

Comment: Recreate the video activity, and use your custom video-activity instead of the system one

Comment: i am not using system's  video or camera  its all custom..!!

Comment: So in your video activity, when you stop the video recording, start the activityA with a Bundle containing your video

Comment: Is there last option to use  Intent -startActivity every where...also for   going back

Comment: Can u explain me this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135449/how-to-return-a-result-through-multiple-activities?rq=1

Comment: Are you really asking me to read that answer, understand that, and afterward explain that to you? You lazy! Read it by your self xD

Comment: i  did it ..bt didnt get solution .

Comment: When starting activityC from activityB, use `Intent activityC = new Intente(...); activityC.setFlag(FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);` So when exiting activityC, the result will be redirected to activityA from B

Answer (score 1):

If from Activity C you want to close Activity B & C and go to A then you have two choices.

1. startActivity A from C with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` this will call `onNewIntent` method from activity A and will remove all activities that are on top of activity A.
2. Change the implementation to have:

   a. From activity B startActivityForResult(Activity C).
   b. In activity C, when it's done call `setResult/finish` 
   c. In activity B, in `onActivityResult` check the request code, if is C request code, `setResult/finish`
   d. Activity A it's visible again with result.

If you don't want to close Activity B & C just start the activity a and pass data to it as you start activity B.

Comment: I have a Add button in Activity A , Now Activity B is Camera_photo capture that capture image and send to A with startActivityResult, and activity B has video button that calls  startActivity to C to capture Video,  Activity C has video capture button and go to Activity D now i want  Activity D to A with video Data

Comment: Point 1. from my answer should do the trick.:)